# Scroll top/bottom of the screen on button click using JavaScript not jQuery also It should work in chrome, IE & mozilla

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to implement a simple top and bottom scroll on button click. the scroll should be smooth in all browsers.

Requirements -

I have two buttons on the page,  on top of the page there is a button called **Down** on clicking on that It should go down to the footer div.

There is one more button on the bottom of the page called **UP** on clicking on that It should go up of the screen.

I have tried one solution but in IE, the scroll is not smooth. How can we make the scroll behavior smooth in all browsers.

Currently I have used the scroll-behavior property in CSS but is it a good practice? Is there any way to do it in JavaScript instead of CSS?

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

NOTE: It should also work in IE.

I would really appreciate your help.

Link of codepen for code- https://codepen.io/Akkanksha1/full/KKgWmgL

Comment: ``scroll-behavior`` does not work in IE.

Comment: Is there any way to make it scroll smooth in IE @NotABot

Comment: You can try the ``scrollTo`` method in JavaScript to achieve somewhat ``scroll-behavior`` is doing. You need to know the dimensions(height and width) in px of the page then accordingly you can achieve. @Akansha Mohanty

Comment: @AkankshaMohanty, Does IE mean the discontinued IE or Edge? Cause you won't find a easy way to do it in IE. You will need a library.

Comment: Yes I searched a lot for a solution that works on IE as well but I didn't find any proper solution. If you will check the codepen link then It is working in IE but not smooth. so is there any way that we can use javascript to add the scroll behavior property as I have used css for that.@NikhilPatil

Comment: The scrollTo method works in IE too?...If we add dimensions(height and width) in px then it will be fixed as there is a high chance that the page height will increase then this solution won't be helpful @NotABot

Comment: @AkankshaMohanty You don't need to add pre-defined height and width values, when the page loads, you can determine the height and width of the page using ``outerHeight`` and ``outerWidth``. Also ``scrollTo`` works in **Internet Explorer**. You can read more about the ``scrollTo`` and it Browser compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: Thank you @NotABot for your suggestion of using scrollTo. It actually worked and also I removed the css property(scroll-behavior) from css file. Could you please check the latest code that I have in codepen and let me know if any improvement needed - https://codepen.io/Akkanksha1/pen/KKgWmgL

Comment: Also for Scrolling down the screen is there any other methods in Javascript than scrollIntoView() method? I have given the div class name to go down to the page..I dont want use any html div class.Is it possible to scroll down the page without any div class in JS? @NotABot

Comment: @AkankshaMohanty Your code looks fine, nothing much to improve. Regarding scrolling without any ``class``, can you tell what exactly you want? We need a reference on which **button/div etc**, the user has clicked to perform the desired action.

Comment: Hi @NotABot. Actually I was trying to scroll to the bottom of the page using Javascript methods only. Using scrollIntoView(), we need to provide the reference class name where the scroll will be stop. Actually this scroll functionality will be used in a website that has many pages and adding the class name will be difficult to maintain in different pages. Therefor I was looking for a solution that on clicking the down arrow It will completely scroll down of the window.

Comment: @AkankshaMohanty First of all please check the compatibility of ``scrollIntoView`` in **Internet Explorer** (If users of the IE, not concerned then it is fine). If managing multiple classes on multiple pages is a problem, you can have as previously suggested ``scrollTo``. Anyhow you will require some **class/Id** on your HTML where there the page will have to scroll(Upward or Downwards). Without any reference, it's not easy to scroll on the DOM

Answer (score 4):

This solution is written in ECMAScript 5 and makes use of [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) in order to synchronize the step calculations with the screen framerate. It works in IE and in modern browsers as well.
It implements the [`easeInOutCubic`](https://easings.net/fr#easeInOutCubic) function, and could be extended to support other easing functions.

```js
function getProgress(_ref) {
  var duration = _ref.duration,
      runTime = _ref.runTime;
  var percentTimeElapsed = runTime / duration;

  function easeOutCubic(x) {
      return x < 0.5 ? 4 * x * x * x : 1 - Math.pow(-2 * x + 2, 3) / 2 ;
  }

  return easeOutCubic(percentTimeElapsed);
};

function getTotalScroll(_ref) {
  var scrollableDomEle = _ref.scrollableDomEle,
      elementLengthProp = _ref.elementLengthProp,
      initialScrollPosition = _ref.initialScrollPosition,
      scrollLengthProp = _ref.scrollLengthProp,
      direction = _ref.direction;
  var totalScroll;

  var documentElement = document.documentElement;
  totalScroll = documentElement.offsetHeight;
  
  return !!~['left', 'top'].indexOf(direction) ? initialScrollPosition : totalScroll - initialScrollPosition;
};

function smoothScroll(_ref2) {
  var scrollableDomEle = window,
      direction = _ref2.direction,
      duration = _ref2.duration,
      scrollAmount = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var startTime = null,
      scrollDirectionProp = null,
      scrollLengthProp = null,
      elementLengthProp = null,
      scrollDirectionProp = 'pageYOffset';
      elementLengthProp = 'innerHeight';
      scrollLengthProp = 'scrollHeight';

  var initialScrollPosition = scrollableDomEle[scrollDirectionProp];
  var totalScroll = getTotalScroll({
    scrollableDomEle: scrollableDomEle,
    elementLengthProp: elementLengthProp,
    initialScrollPosition: initialScrollPosition,
    scrollLengthProp: scrollLengthProp,
    direction: direction
  });

  if (!isNaN(scrollAmount) && scrollAmount < totalScroll) {
    totalScroll = scrollAmount;
  }

  var scrollOnNextTick = function scrollOnNextTick(timestamp) {
    var runTime = timestamp - startTime;
    var progress = getProgress({
      runTime: runTime,
      duration: duration
    });

    if (!isNaN(progress)) {
      var scrollAmt = progress * totalScroll;
      var scrollToForThisTick = direction === 'bottom' ? scrollAmt + initialScrollPosition : initialScrollPosition - scrollAmt;

      if (runTime < duration) {
        var xScrollTo = 0;
        var yScrollTo = scrollToForThisTick;
        window.scrollTo(xScrollTo, yScrollTo);

        requestAnimationFrame(scrollOnNextTick);
      } else {
        var _scrollAmt = totalScroll;
        var scrollToForFinalTick = direction === 'bottom' ? _scrollAmt + initialScrollPosition : initialScrollPosition - _scrollAmt;
        var _xScrollTo = 0;
        var _yScrollTo = scrollToForFinalTick;
        window.scrollTo(_xScrollTo, _yScrollTo);
      }
    }
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
    startTime = timestamp;
    scrollOnNextTick(timestamp);
  });
};


function scrollToTop() {
  smoothScroll({ duration: 2000, direction: 'top' });
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  smoothScroll({ duration: 2000, direction: 'bottom' });
}

document.getElementById('scroll-to-bottom').addEventListener('click', scrollToBottom);
document.getElementById('scroll-to-top').addEventListener('click', scrollToTop);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red
}

#scroll-to-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#scroll-to-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="scroll-to-bottom">Scroll to bottom</button>
  <button id="scroll-to-top">Scroll to top</button>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't quite go all the way to the top or bottom

Comment: Really? For me it does

Comment: it's 70–100px shy for me in Chrome, but seems like a good solution otherwise

Comment: yes, doesnt go all the way up or down on Chrome, but nice code, incredible what it takes to make this work on IE

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just tested on Chrome 87 and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution that works in Chrome and also in other web browsers like IE and Mozilla. My goal was to have a up & down scroll on the page and the below code works like a magic for me.

JS Code -

```
//Get the button
const scrollToTopBtn = document.getElementById("scrollToTopBtn");
const scrollToBottomBtn = document.getElementById("scrollToBottomBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 1000px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1000 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1000) {
    scrollToTopBtn.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    scrollToTopBtn.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
};
function bottomFunction(){
  document.getElementById('site-footer').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}


scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  topFunction();
});

scrollToBottomBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  bottomFunction();
});
```

Working demo - https://codepen.io/Akkanksha1/full/KKgWmgL

Answer (score 1):

@AkankshaMohanty this all depends on how far you would like to go back, as in IE 11? Or further back? Are polyfills ok?

Well anyway, without further ado, the most primitive way can be the best.

Classic jQuery approach, this should work with older jQuery versions(the new version do not support IE anymore)

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#myElem").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

The scroll up or down you may implement yourself, but the main cross browser issue is a non issue with the above code, something like jQuery 1. or 2. should work.

here is a plugin to make it work http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html, there are some other polyfills which I am not going to link to. With requirements like "work in IE without a fallback option" , elegance is the first victim.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any large code. Just you need `scrollTop` property. It indicates the distance scrolled from top. To go to top you just have to set it to 0 and to go to bottom you have to scroll to maximum height.
To make it smooth it is better to go to custom approach to provide cross platform support. For example you can see the code which is self explanatory and ready to use

```
function scrollToTop(){
  var interval=setInterval(()=>{
    var i=document.body.scrollTop;
    document.body.scrollTop=i-1;
    if((i-1)===0){
       clearInterval(this);
    }
  },30)
}
function scrollToBottom(){
  var maxHeight=document.body.offsetHeight-window.clientHeight; 
    var interval=setInterval(()=>{
    var i=document.body.scrollTop;
    document.body.scrollTop=i+1;
    if((i+1)===maxHeight){
       clearInterval(this);
    }
  },30)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top}, 800, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#section1 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: pink;
}
#section2 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: purple;
}
a {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Click on the link to see the "smooth" scrolling effect.</h1>
    <div class="main" id="section1">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        
        <a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>
    </div>

    <div class="main" id="section2">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```